# adding text in memory allocated

Tags: c++, memcpy

i have created certain amount of memory

```
char* str;
str = char(char*) malloc(15);
```

when i do this

```
memcpy(str, "AB", 2);
memcpy(str, "CDEFG", 5)
cout<<"Value of str: "<<str<<endl;
```

the output is value of value of str: DEFGH
what i see is it overwrites the previous memcpy
how do i keep on adding text to str so that everytime text is added it gets added to previous str value, not overwrite previous value and start from start

Comment: Why not simply use `strcat`. For that matter why not use `std::string` to beginwith.

Comment: `memcpy(str + 2, "CDEFG", 5);`

Comment: [tag:c++]? `std::string str = "AB"; str += "CDEFG";` Done.

Answer (score 2):

You use an `std::string`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  std::string str = "AB";
  str+= "CDEFG";
  std::cout << str << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strcat` rather than `memcpy`.

Or use `memcpy(str +2, "CDEFG", 5);

[And remove the +1 when you print the values, since it should certainly print CDEFG, not DEFGH - this is obviously a bug in your `cout` stream handling...]

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of how many characters you have written and adjust your pointer. In your example:

```
memcpy(str, "AB", 2);

memcpy(str+2, "CDEFG", 5)
```

Besides that, your string will not be NULL terminated. For the last copy, you need one extra character to copy '\0' too. Either use strcpy or best of all, use a std::string:

```
#include <string>
int main()
{
  std::string s = "AB";
  s += "CDEFG";
}
```